# How to reflect BEM blocks in Aurelia views

Tags: css, aurelia, bem

I'm about to start a new project using Aurelia and I'm considering to use it in conjunction with CSS BEM methodology.

**First question:** Is this basically considered a good match or are there any alternatives which "fit" better with Aurelia?

**Main question:**

Best explained with an example for some custom Aurelia view (an app header):

```
<template>
    <div class="AppHeader">
        <span class="AppHeader-logo"></span>
        <span class="AppHeader-text"></span>
        <app-menu></app-menu>
    </div>
</template>
```

When embedded into another view, this leads to a resulting DOM like this (simplified):

```
<app-header>
    <div class="AppHeader">
        <span class="AppHeader-logo"></span>
        <span class="AppHeader-text"></span>
        <app-menu>
                    <!-- ... -->
        </app-menu>
    </div>
</app-header>
```

Obviously, the wrapper `div` with the `AppHeader` class is kind of superfluous since there's also the `app-header` tag. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to assign the CSS class `AppHeader` (which is needed for BEM) to the base element of the view (the `template` tag in the view file).

Are there any alternative ways that I'm not aware of or is it considered "good" practice (or at least acceptable) to have many wrapper elements inside views which somehow bloat the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized, that putting custom classes on the custom elements themselves (the `template`) actually works, so I can simply write something like this:

```
<template class="AppHeader">
    <span class="AppHeader-logo"></span>
    <span class="AppHeader-text"></span>
    <app-menu></app-menu>
</template>
```

---

**Edit / Additional info**

This won't work if the view is a "base view" of a route since the `template` element won't be rendered at all in this scenario but is replaced by the `router-view` element.

Comment: I did the same initially and have switch to this method, it's much easier when you use `flex` as your template is the container.

Comment: In the case of routing you'd set the block as a route parameter and render it onto the route container using a class interpolation

Answer (score 0):

I believe that even a hundred extra DOM nodes is not a problem for contemporary browsers but if it's really important to avoid them you may try custom tags instead of classes (see list of restrictions here https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#why-are-custom-tags-not-used-for-blocks-in-bem).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `@containerless` will solve your problems:

In your view model:

```
@containerless
export class AppHeader {
  ...
}
```

In this way, the `<app-header>` container will not be rendered.

If your component is a view-only component, you can declare `containerless` in the `<template>` tag:

```
<template containerless>
    <div class="AppHeader">
        <span class="AppHeader-logo"></span>
        <span class="AppHeader-text"></span>
        <app-menu></app-menu>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Containerless works in some situations but I found it wasn't possible in others so I tend to avoid it for the most part.